# Exporting MS Access Tables with Time stamp in filename

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have created some daily reports ( MS access tables) of my team in access and exporting that data to excel with Macros. While exporting, is there any way I can export with date in the file name. Presently, I am adding the date in the file name manually after exporting. Its a time consuming process for me.As i am very poor in VBA programming i am seeking help from seniors here.

Thanks
santhosha

Comment: What form of help are you looking for? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't know if this is doable or what .If it is ,then how can i get started?.I want some experts here to throw some light on this.

Comment: Forgive me for my directness: 1. Yes I will guarantee you that there is a way to solve your problem somehow. 2. However with the limited amount of information given it's going to be very, very hard to help you. Have you really read all the things in the link above?